# QCoreApplication::exit() from non-GUI subproject

Tags: qt, qcoreapplication

Consider this case: there is a SUBDIRS Qt project which includes GUI subproject, which uses "gui" Qt module, and non-GUI subproject which is a dynamic library used by the GUI subproject, which uses only "core" Qt module. Is it correct to call QCoreApplication::exit() from the non-GUI subproject?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that it is not virtual function. Post your comment as an answer and I upvote it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment into this answer:

[`QApplication`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) inherits from [`QCoreApplication`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html).
Since [`exit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exit) is not a virtual function, you can call it from the non-GUI code.